# Draw Candlestick Charts in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-charts

I am a beginner to iOS.

I need *to draw* **Candlestick Chart**.

Is any framework available to draw this?

Can anyone one guide me to implement candlestick chart?

[image: Example of candlestick chart]

Comment: Try this https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Thank you... it is working....

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library for your requirement and here are some related library for CandleStick Chart

**scichart :** https://www.scichart.com/ios-candlestick-chart-demo/

**Core Plot :** http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

**Shinobi Charts (PAID) :** https://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobicharts

But Among all Charts is best lib for showing your data with charts and [danielgindi](https://github.com/danielgindi) managed this lib nicely.

Hope This info will helps you!